# My UIView not resizing width on rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a topbarlogo(header) that I load from an .xib -file. I use the following code to make the view fit on screen, because applying constraints in the xib does not work to make it fit the screen right (even though I would like it if I could just make constraints on the view as usual, but in the xib):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   NSArray *nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RaymioHeaderView" owner:nil options:nil];
   CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
   UIView *topView = [nibContents lastObject];
   topView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenBounds.size.width, 78);
   [self.view addSubview:topView];
}
```

Now when I rotate the screen to landscape it stays at the same width instead of filling out. I was kind of thinking that viewDidLoad would be called again when redrawing after rotation. Any help appreciated.

Comment: use auto layout life will be easy with different iPhone sizes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, viewDidLoad will not be called again when the interface rotates. If constraints are out of the question, I usually like to use an autoresizingMask instead.

`topView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;`

Comment: well that just worked smoothly...:) I will look into why this works.   I would like to use constraints, but I don't know how to apply them since I load my view from a nib (which obv only contains the view that needs to be scaled), do you have an idea how to?

Comment: Create a new UIView subclass and override awakeAfterUsingCoder to load the interface from your xib, add a plain UIView to your storyboard and set the class to be your new UIView subclass, then set the constraints as needed.

Comment: my xib view is actually already a subclass of UIView, and holds a method called presentHeader:(UIViewController*). I will look into the awakeAfterUsingCoder method, because I don't know that at all. I was trying to avoid having to make an UIView for every view controller I have, hence the presentHeader: method. I appreciate your help.